gRPC Connection Issue in Flutter/Dart: Specified Port Not Being Used
I'm trying to use gRPC in Flutter/Dart but am encountering the following error:
gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE, message: Error connecting: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 58434, details: null, rawResponse: null, trailers: {})

Despite specifying port 9991, it seems to be using a random port.
Can anyone suggest a solution?
Note:
The gRPC server started on localhost:9991, and the connection is successful in my React/TypeScript project.
I'm using a Mac, and neither 127.0.0.1 nor 0.0.0.0 is working.
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';
import 'package:my_app/gen/grpc/auth/v1/auth.pbgrpc.dart';

Future<void> useLogin() async {
  final req = SigninRequest(
      email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
      password: 'hogehoge',
      organizationId: 'xxxxx');

  final channel = ClientChannel(
      'localhost',
      port: 9991,
      options: const ChannelOptions(
        connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
        connectionTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
        credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure(),
      )
  );
  final options = CallOptions(
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
  );

  final client = AuthServiceClient(channel, options: options);
  
  try {
    final response = await client.signin(req);
    log("success!!!");
    log(response.toString());
  } catch (e) {
    log("error!!!");
    log(e.toString());
  }
}



I made a mistake...
I'm using an Android emulator on macOS, so the correct address is '10.0.2.2'.
